# jQuery datetime formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a working jQuery plugin (or a javascript 'library') for formatting datetimes? I found some, but they were:

- not working with hours and minutes (the one from datapicker)
- not fully functional - can't give you names of months, leading zeroes, etc.
- are just a piece of code written in some blog.

Of course I can implement it, but it'd be better to reuse one. I seek functionality similar to Java's [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a JavaScript implementation of the `format()` method of Java's `SimpleDateFormat`: http://www.timdown.co.uk/code/simpledateformat.php

The code is a few years old and I'd do it a bit differently now, but it's well tested and works.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) ?

It has a pattern recognition to format dates that is easy to use and has plenty of localisation files available.

ie: `Date.today().toString("d-MMM-yyyy HH:mm")`

Answer (score 2):

I use http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it fits all your requirements, but this looks good one:

- [jquery-dateFormat](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat)

Comment: that's the one that isn't functional enough :)